# How can I access an object instance's context from within a predefined function passed to the "bind" method invoked on the instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, bind, anonymous-function

I have this snippet:

```
var test_img = $("<img />");
test_img.attr("src", img_url);
test_img.unbind("load");

console.log(test_img);

test_img.bind("load", function ()
    {
        console.log(this);
    });
```

The first `console.log` outputs:

```
[img]
    0: img  // expandable
    length: 1
    __proto__: Object[0]  // expandable
```

The second `console.log` outputs:

```
<img src=​"/​images/​Tree.jpg">​
```

Why are the two outputs different?

Also, I need to define the function that gets passed to `test_img.bind` elsewhere. I.e.,

```
function predefined_function()
{
    console.log(new_this);
}

var test_img = $("<img />");
test_img.attr("src", img_url);
test_img.unbind("load");

console.log(test_img);

test_img.bind("load", predefined_function);
```

How can I make it so that `new_this` is the same as `this` in the original snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer to your first question, the difference is because the constructor of the first output is `jQuery.fn.init`, but the constructor of the second output is `HTMLImageElement`. You can access image from first output using `test_img[0]`.
If you want to use some predefined function, just replace `new_this` with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/y89zk2k8/1/

```
var textDiv = $("<div />").append("click me :)"),
    func = function() {
        var $me = $(this);
    console.log($me);
    };

textDiv.off("click");

console.log(textDiv);

textDiv.on("click", func);

$("body").append(textDiv);
```

1. To make new_this same as this: You need to change it to the Jquery Oject in the event response function.
2. Define the function that gets passed to the event elsewhere: Pass the function as param to the event response function.
3. Use .on to replace .bind, because .bind may be removed from future versions at any time. There is no reason to keep using .bind and every reason to prefer .on instead.